# useEffect only runs on hot reload

Tags: reactjs, events, mouseevent, use-effect

I have a parent/child component where when there is a swipe event occurring in the child the parent component should fetch a new profile. The problem is the **useEffect** in the child component to set up the **eventListeneners** currently is not running, only occasionally on hot-reload which in reality should run basically every time.

**Child component**

```
function Profile(props: any) {
  const [name] = useState(`${props.profile.name.title} ${props.profile.name.first} ${props.profile.name.last}`);
  const [swiped, setSwiped] = useState(0)
  const backgroundImage = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${props.profile.picture.large})`
  };
  const cardRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const card = cardRef.current

  let startX:any = null;

  function unify (e:any) { return e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0] : e };

  function lock (e:any) { if (card) {startX = unify(e).clientX; console.log(startX)} }

  function move (e: any) {
    console.log('move')
    if(startX) {
      let differenceX = unify(e).clientX - startX, sign = Math.sign(differenceX);
      if(sign < 0 || sign > 0) {
        setSwiped((swiped) => swiped +1)
        props.parentCallback(swiped);
        startX = null
      }
    }
    }

  // Following code block does not work

  useEffect(() => {
    if (card) {
    console.log(card)
    card.addEventListener('mousedown', lock, false);
    card.addEventListener('touchstart', lock, false);
    
    card.addEventListener('mouseup', move, false);
    card.addEventListener('touchend', move, false);
    }
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="heading-1">{name}</h1>
      <div ref={cardRef} className="card" style={backgroundImage}>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Parent component**

```
function Profiles() {
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [swiped, setSwiped] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
      getProfiles()
    }, [swiped])

    const callback = useCallback((swiped) => {
      setSwiped(swiped);
      console.log(swiped);
    }, []);

    const getProfiles = () => {
      fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setProfiles(result.results);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
    }
    if (error) {
        return <h1 className="heading-1">Error: {error.message}</h1>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <h1 className="heading-1">Loading...</h1>;
    } else {
        return (
            <div id="board">
            {profiles.map(profile => ( 
                <Profile key={profile.id.value} profile={profile} parentCallback={callback}/>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent components swiped state to change, you need to pass "setSwiped" from the parent to the child compenent. You will also need to pass "swiped" to the child to use its current value to calculate the new value. I'm going to assume you declared the useState in the child component trying to set the parents state of the same name, so I'm going to remove that useState Declaration in the child altogether.

Here's an example of passing the setSwiped method and swiped value to the child:

**PARENT**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import './Index.css';
import Profile from './Profile'

function Profiles() {
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [swiped, setSwiped] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
      getProfiles()
    }, [swiped])

    const callback = useCallback((swiped) => {
      setSwiped(swiped);
      console.log(swiped);
    }, []);

    const getProfiles = () => {
      fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setProfiles(result.results);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
    }
    if (error) {
        return <h1 className="heading-1">Error: {error.message}</h1>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <h1 className="heading-1">Loading...</h1>;
    } else {
        return (
            <div id="board">
            {profiles.map(profile => ( 
                <Profile key={profile.id.value} profile={profile} parentCallback={callback} setSwiped={setSwiped} swiped={swiped}/>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Profiles;
```

**CHILD**

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect   }  from 'react';
import './Index.css';

function Profile(props: any) {
  const [name] = useState(`${props.profile.name.title} ${props.profile.name.first} ${props.profile.name.last}`);
  const backgroundImage = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${props.profile.picture.large})`
  };
  const cardRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const card = cardRef.current

  let startX:any = null;

  function unify (e:any) { return e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0] : e };

  function lock (e:any) { if (card) {startX = unify(e).clientX; console.log(startX)} }

  function move (e: any) {
    console.log('move')
    if(startX) {
      let differenceX = unify(e).clientX - startX, sign = Math.sign(differenceX);
      if(sign < 0 || sign > 0) {
        props.setSwiped((props.swiped) => props.swiped +1)
        props.parentCallback(props.swiped);
        startX = null
      }
    }
    }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (card) {
    console.log(card)
    card.addEventListener('mousedown', lock, false);
    card.addEventListener('touchstart', lock, false);
    
    card.addEventListener('mouseup', move, false);
    card.addEventListener('touchend', move, false);
    }
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="heading-1">{name}</h1>
      <div ref={cardRef} className="card" style={backgroundImage}>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

I'm hoping I didn't miss anything here.
Best of luck.